# Wordpress Form Not Submitting Data

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, .htaccess

I am working on wordpress site, i created custom form, in which i am getting voucher code and after validating this code , submitting this form to another url , defined in form action, here is jquery for this work,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        $( "#submit_btn_redeem" ).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
            var form = $("#form-voucher");
            var voucher_code = $("#voucher_code").val();
            var btn = $(this);
            if(voucher_code!=""){
                $("#voucher_code").removeClass("error-fld");
                btn.prop('disabled', true);
                btn.attr("disabled","disabled");
                $(".loading").show();
                var action_data = {
                    'action': 'check_voucher_code',
                    'voucher_code': voucher_code
                };

                $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: ajaxurl, 
                    data: action_data, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) { 
                        $(".loading").hide();
                        btn.prop('disabled',false);
                        btn.removeAttr("disabled");

                        if(response.status==1){
                            $(".response").html(response.message);
                            $(".response").show().delay(2000).hide(0);
                            alert($("#voucher_code").val());
                            //return false;
                            setTimeout(function(){ 
                                document.getElementById("form-voucher").submit(); 
                            }, 1000);


                        }else{
                            $("#voucher_code").addClass("error-fld");
                            $(".response").html(response.message);
                            $(".response").show().delay(3000).hide(0);

                        }
                    }
                });

            }else{
                $("#voucher_code").addClass("error-fld");
            }



        });
    });
</script>
```

Problem is when it submit on given url , it is first redirect to 301 with POST method, then again generate GET request with no parameter and sumitted to that url, I have dumped $_REQUEST on action url, not getting any data here, i have also check .htaccess and redirect plugin, there is no such url exists for redirection, the question is submitting form with post method redirect, while with GET method its work fine, any body can help

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined the action function in your function.php file in your theme, which will look something like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_voucher_code', 'functiontohook' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_voucher_code', 'functiontohook' );
```

After that you need to specify the action in you ajax request which you have done. In functiontohook you can get your all json data and do anything that you want to do. Let me know if anything is not clear. I hope this will help you out.